# Can a particle with non-zero rest mass "tunnel" into the tachyon world without having to cross the $m=\infty$ barrier?

Tags: special-relativity, mass, faster-than-light, tachyon

[image: Relativity Tunnel]

In the above diagram, I've indicated the variation of mass of a particle with its velocity using the solid curve for $v < c$ and using the long dashed lines (which lie in the complex plane) for $v > c$.

I know the particle cannot be accelerated to $v >= c$ as its mass reaches infinity when $v$ approaches light speed, but I was just wondering, if it's possible for the particle to somehow "tunnel" into the tachyon world bypassing the barrier (indicated by the curved arrow), especially when the rest mass is low?

If this is, well, physically feasible, what physical process/condition would be a possible candidate that enables such a transition?

Comment: We prefer to avoid the old concept of relativistic mass on this site. Please see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/133376/123208

Comment: But anyway, the problem isn't *just* that $\gamma\to\infty$ as the particle approaches lightspeed. As your question alludes to, $\gamma$ becomes imaginary for $v>c$. How do you tunnel to such a state?

Comment: @PM2Ring Well, to be honest, I don't have an answer to how such a transition can happen. I can't visualize how an object with imaginary mass would look like or behave; nor guess what would happen to the "real" part of the mass after the transition. What I'm trying to understand here is whether any factor(s) outside relativity (such as QM effects) can play a role on the process and allow anomalous behavior (particularly for very low masses, as I hinted in the question).

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks for the link.

Comment: @PM2Ring : Imaginary gamma can be understood at least in 1+1 dimensions as exchanging the spatial and temporal axes of the reference frame, i.e. "space becomes time and time becomes space". However, this doesn't work as nice in 3+1 dimensions, so I'm not sure. That said, it only matters if we want to define a "reference frame" for tachyons, versus considering observing them from our own.

Comment: Also, regarding the question, I'd suggest the answer is **no** because we have not observed such tunnelling. However, it would be very interesting to elaborate on the **reasons** for why that is. I _suspect_ - but am not knowledgeable enough to say for sure - that it has to do with the same as why an electron can't suddenly "tunnel" into having a mass of 1000 keV, for example, if put in an environment with suitable energy. The mass is a fixed parameter of the quantum field that those particles inhabit.

Comment: @The_Sympathizer Ok. It's related to what happens in Schwarzschild coordinates when a particle crosses the event horizon of a black hole. However, in that scenario, the outside universe is causally disconnected from events inside the event horizon. And we can switch to other coordinates that don't have a coordinate singularity at the event horizon.

Comment: @PM 2Ring : Yes regarding the gamma factor in the Lorentz transformation. Keep in mind though that "reference frames" in general _are_ coordinate systems, just with a difference in semantic content; so there's no reason to limit "tachyonic reference frames" to _only_ the Lorentz transformations of bradyonic ones. Moreover, one can argue the idea of Lorentz-transforming a bradyonic situation to a tachyonic one is kind of "against the spirit" of those transformations because what they are "really" about is they are _symmetries which preserve the physics,_ and

Comment: the physics in a tachyonic reference frame - however you want to construct that - is _necessarily_ different than that in a bradyonic one, because for one, logic would say that bradyonic particles would have to be regarded by the tachyonic observer as moving faster than light. The point is you can _make sense_ of the imaginary, but the imaginary Lorentz transformations are not necessarily symmetries of physical dynamics.

Comment: That said, if we assume Lorentz symmetry _of hypothetical tachyonic dynamics,_ then we can use ordinary(!) Lorentz transformations to transform _between tachyonic frames_ that we define using some suitably tachyonic processes, just not bradyonic to tachyonic or vice versa. Namely, the time axis of an "inertially"-moving, i.e. straight and steady, tachyon must lie long a spacelike line, and a Lorentz transformation can transform one such line into another. But the precise form of such tachyonic frames depends on what the tachyonic dynamics would be.

Comment: There is quite a lot of mainstream literature about “instantaneous quantum tunneling”, including experimental observations such as [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1038/s41586-019-1028-3) (see also [popular account](https://www.quantamagazine.org/quantum-tunnel-shows-particles-can-break-the-speed-of-light-20201020/)), though discussions do not usually use the word “tachyon”. So I think this question does have a positive answer (in a sense).

Answer (score 0):

Remember, speed is relative: no matter how fast a particle is going relative to you, in its own rest frame its speed is $0$ and the speed of light is $c$. So your hypothetical "tunneling" would, in the initial rest frame of the particle, consist of a particle spontaneously changing from being at rest to being a tachyon. This would appear to violate conservation of momentum, at the very least.

Comment: But could a bradyon-tachyon pair swap velocities — the bradyon becoming a tachyon and the tachyon becoming a bradyon — without interacting, thereby conserving momentum and energy?

Comment: Such an exchange would be an "interaction". Would it be possible? I suppose you could arrange it so that momentum, energy, and appropriate quantum numbers are conserved. I think experimental evidence (from the LHC and from proton decay experiments) would indicate that such interactions must be, at best, extremely unlikely.